# Changing form elements Enabled property based on other form elements

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I would like to know correct way of changing Enabled property of dfm component based on other components state.

For example, I have **edit3** that should be enabled only if value of some **edit1** is in set of **{'value1', 'value2'}** and **edit2** value is **'edit2Val'**

What is the most correct way to do this?

Or is there better way then to make 2 **onChange** events which will look like this?

```
procedure tFrm1.edit1Change(Sender : TObject);
begin
  edit3ChangeEnabled;   
  //some specific code
end;

procedure tFrm1.edit2Change(Sender : TObject);
begin
  edit3ChangeEnabled;  
  //some other specific code 
end;

procedure tFrm1.edit3ChangeEnabled;
var 
  Enabled : Boolean;
begin
  Enabled := checkEdit1Vals and checkEdit2Vals;
  edit3.Enabled := Enabled;
end;
```

Comment: There are better ways, but they will involve separating model and presentation into separate layers. That's a big task and not really suited to a question here.

Comment: I usually places all Enabled and Visible logic handling in one method called UpdateControlStates and then call that method whenever relevant controls changes.

Comment: You can use a `TAction(List).OnUpdate` event handler to set the properties based on the current state of the components.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of things TAction was designed to help you do. There's a tutorial in the documentation about how to use Actions.